# Exactly once with Kafka + Spark Streaming

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming, spark-streaming-kafka

*Is it possible to achieve exactly once by handling Kafka topic at Spark Streaming application?*

To achieve exactly once you need the following things:

1. Exactly once on Kafka producer to Kafka broker. This is achieved by Kafka's 0.11 idempotent producer. *But is Kafka 0.11 to Spark Streaming integration production ready?* I found [this JIRA ticket with lots of bugs.](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-18057)
2. Exactly once on Kafka broker to Spark Streaming app. *Could it be achieved?* Because of Spark Streaming app failures, the application can read some data twice, right? As solution, can I persist computation results & last handled event uuid to Redis transactionaly?
3. Exactly once on trasforming data by Spark Streaming app. This is out-of-the-box property of RDD.
4. Exactly once on persisting results. Is solved at the 2nd statement by transactionaly persisting last event uuid to Redis.